# How to log all routes acess?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I build api service using laravel.
I want to log all acess to the api routes
I though somewhere in the routes.php put some code that get the requested route? any help? thanks

laravel 4

Comment: Your webserver will log all requests and you can filter the API ones by URL. What additional logging do you want to implement?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I want to have some analytics about the api usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a route filter first

```
Route::filter('log', function($route, $request, $response)
{
    // log work
});
```

then apply the filter to your route

```
Route::get('api', array('before' => 'log', function()
{
    return 'logged!';
}));
```

I think you can also get the log from the access log of your web server.

Comment: but how in the log filter I get the requested route?

Comment: `Route::filter('log', function($route, $request) { // do stuff });`.  This makes those objects accessible inside your route so you can get the url, parameters, and many other things.